# NReco.PdfToImageConverter Warning message box when converting PDF to Image

Tags: c#, nreco

`NReco.PdfToImageConverter Warning message box when converting PDF to Image`

When calling `PdfToImageConverter.GenerateImage (or GenerateImages)` there are cases that I'm getting a message box with a warning message `Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment.`

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the message box and be able to handle it by code.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use try / catch statement. NReco references `PdfToImageException` as an exception that can be caught.

Comment: Thank you Jawad. But no exception is generated. Just the message box.